# Error in emotion/styled package, cannot find answer ANYWHERE

Tags: npm, meteor, emotion, emotion-js

I keep getting the following error, I'm using meteor 2.1  currently

Error: A new entrypoint in the `@emotion/styled` package, `@emotion/styled/base`, has replaced the `@emotion/styled-base` package. Please remove this package and use `@emotion/styled/base` instead.

i cannot find ANY way to install this @emotion/styled/base package. @emotion/styled-base is installed and i cannot create a build suddenly.

any suggestions???

I'm using react.js

Comment: have you already tried deleting `package-lock.json` and running `meteor npm install` once more? Can you also post your `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@emotion/styled/base` isn't a package you need to install, but rather its a submodule of the `@emotion/styled` package.

I have a hunch that you are not using `@emotion/styled-base` directly, so most likely what you have is a version mismatch where you have a newer version of `@emotion/styled` installed, but that package is written for an older version. You'll probably just need to locate this offending package and update it.

If this isn't the case, then you'll just need to replace your imports for `@emotion/styled-base` with ones for `@emotion/styled/base`

Comment: no im not using emotion/styled-base anywhere directly. what do you mean by this sentence?

Comment: most likely what you have is a version mismatch where you have a newer version of @emotion/styled installed, but that package is written for an older version

Comment: what do you mean, that package , which package

Comment: im using @emotion/styled": "^11.1.5", if that helps

Comment: What I mean is, if you are not directly importing `@emotion/styled-base` in your app, then there must be another package, possibly one that your app uses, that is importing it.

If your app doesn't have a direct dependency on `@emotion/styled-base` try running `npm ls @emotion/styled-base` to see which package depends on it.